# Changed HTML reverts back to original HTML after switching pages, NOT submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For class, I'm trying to build a single page web page using jquery. One of the components of this is changing the HTML to find the correct ID to show the proper information needed.

I'm running into an issue where after the HTML is changed, the HTML is reverted to its original text. I've done some googling and I learned that it's reverting because of the page switch. Most of the questions already asked about this are dealing with form submissions so I'm not really sure how to deal with it in my case.

What I've tried already is having a global variable that keeps track of the ID but when I switch pages, the global variable also gets reset to its original value. I know that the value is getting reset because I have a console log of before and after.

```
function createList() {
let liArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("oneMusic"));
liArray.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var parm = this.getAttribute("data-parm"); // passing in the record.Id
        document.getElementById("IDparmHere").textContent = parm;

        console.log(
            "parm: " + document.getElementById("IDparmHere").innerHTML
        );

        param = parseInt(parm);
        console.log("param" + param);
        // now jump to our page that will use that one item
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.location.href = "index.html#details";
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

}

And then the code that handles transferring pages. To note, `param` is the global var.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
createList();

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details", function (event) {
    console.log("param 2: " + param);
    let localID = param;
    let idx = GetArrayPointer(localID);

    console.log("local id: " + localID);
    console.log("arrayPointer: " + arrayPointer);
    document.getElementById("oneTitle").innerHTML =
        "The title is: " + songArray[idx].Song;
});
```

});

So the createList() does a bunch of things but at the end of it, it adds an event listener to each of the li elements. When you click on it, you pull the specific ID of that li and then you get transferred to the details page.

By the time the code reaches the details page, both the HTML and the global var revert back to their original values, which makes it useless in figuring out the ID.

For example, if #IDparmHere was changed from "blank" to "1", then after the page switch happens, #IDparmHere is changed back to "blank".
I set the global var as null initially, after it's changed from null to 1 or 2 or 3, after the page switch it goes back to null.

Also, `parm` is supposed to be "param" but the instructor that gave us the skeleton of this code has dyslexia so..

Comment: Can you clarify:  You're creating a SPA (single-page-application) and you're worried about when the "page switches"?  You're creating a SPA yet you have `document.location.href = `?  Looks we have different definitions of a *single page* application (ie you don't load new "pages" as there's only a *single page*).   Essentially, your global ID is being reset because you're resetting the page by reloading it.

Comment: @freedomn-m well no it would be spa because I only have a single page. There's only 1 html file, which is the index.

Comment: Right, that's not an SPA, it's an application with one page.  Essentially, your global ID is being reset because you're resetting the page by reloading it.

Comment: @freedomn-m "because you're resetting the page by reloading it" Yes I agree this is the crux of the issue. I was wondering how I would be able to avoid this issue. I know with forms, you can just add a return false in there somewhere but I'm not quite familiar with how I would do that in this instance.

Comment: SPAs work by using ajax to load the content rather than reload the whole page.  So you would replace `document.location.href = "index.html#details";` with something like `$("#details").load("index.html #details")` (note the space).  This would then not reset any js variables or any other HTML (such as menus).   Depending on the application, you would load different "pages" as required, so you might instead do `$("#details").load("details.html?param=" + parm)` - single page application means the application stays on a single page, it doesn't mean there's only one html "file".

Comment: You could open the new page with `let newPage = window.open("address","name")`. In this way you're going to open the new page in a  new tab.  In the new page you should be able to reference the old page with window.opener, thus `window.opener.focus()`. When you have focus newPage.close(). But it's involved and not a Spa. Instead you can implement a spa with the history object and its methods,`display:none`, and code already embedded in your page with given id. Or loading pages with ajax but this will not allow you to navigate the history (instead previous method do)

Comment: @freedomn-m ya sorry you're correct. I'm not building a spa. I'm just building an application with one page as you have stated. But I won't be allowed to use ajax here. Your first suggestion only fires the javascript but doesn't "switch" the page. But I think it's given me a pretty good idea of where to start so thanks for that!

Comment: @Umbert I'm unfortunately not allowed to open any new pages :/ Part of the assignment. Gotta keep everything on one page

Comment: Then to keep "global" variables, you'll need a way to "store" *or* "pass" them to the newly loaded page.  Either pass in as a parameter:  `location.href = "index.html?id=" + global_id` or use something like [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (there's also lots of [questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+localstorage) about localstorage)

Comment: @freedomn-m localstorage is an excellent idea and I will definitely try that tomorrow. Thank you for the suggestion!